# php errors are not being shown despite display_errors being on

Tags: php

My problem is that I have a site, which isn't being shown and when I get rid of my php code it is shown, but there are no php errors being shown at all.

Based on answers to other questions I've tried all of these solutions:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', 'phplog.log');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

And set the `display_errors` in php.ini to on, which is also shown when I use `phpinfo();`, which was said to check in another answer. So why isn't anything being shown?

This is what I have:
index.php:

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('error_log', 'phplog.log');
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  phpinfo();
    include("cubenex-api.php");
    include("php.ini")
    $connections = new Connections();
    $connections->connect();
    $user = new User($connections, "test");
?>
```

And loads of html and css which isn't important

And the cubenex-api.php file:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', 'phplog.log');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
class User{
    public $NAME, $STATUS, $SINCE, $SEEN, $FAVOURITE, $LOCATION, $BIRTHDATE, $ONLINE, $LANGUAGES;
    private $PASSWORD;
    public $RANK;
    public $PERMISSIONS;
    public $EMAIL;
    public $GUEST;

public function __construct($connections, $uuid){
    $pl = $connections->$players->query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE UUID = '".$uuid."'");
    if ($p->num_rows > 0){
        $p = $pl->fetch_assoc();
        $g = $connections->$players->query("SELECT * FROM general WHERE UUID = '".$uuid."'");
        $general = $g->fetch_assoc();
        $NAME = $general["NAME"];
        $RANK = $general["RANK"];
        $EMAIL = $p["EMAIL"];
        $STATUS = $p["STATUS"];
        $SINCE = $p["SINCE"];
        $SEEN = $p["SEEN"];
        $PASSWORD = $p["PASSWORD"];
        $FAVOURITE = $p["FAVOURITE"];
        $LOCATION = $p["LOCATION"];
        $BIRTHDATE = $p["BIRTHDATE"];
        $ONLINE = $p["ONLINE"];
        $LANGUAGES = $p["LANGUAGES"];
        $PERMISSIONS = new Permissions($RANK, $connections);
        $GUEST = false;
    }else{
        $NAME = "Guest";
        $PERMISSIONS = new Permissions("Guest", $connections);
        $GUEST = true;
    }
}
}

class Permissions{
    private $permissions;
    private $cons;

public function __construct($rank, $connections){
    $cons = $connections;
    $result = $connections->$website->query("SELECT * FROM permissions WHERE RANK = '".$rank."'");
    $permissions = explode(",", $result["PERMISSIONS"]);
}

public function __construct(){
    $permissions = array();
}

public function hasPermission($permission){
    return in_array($permission, $permissions);
}

public function givePermission($permission){
    array_push($permissions, $permission);
}

public function takePermission($permission){
    if (in_array($permission, $permissions)){
        unset($permissions[array_search($permission, $permissions)]);
    }
}

public function upload($rank){
    $cons->$website->query("UPDATE permissions SET PERMISSIONS = '".implode(",", $permissions)."' WHERE RANK = '".$rank."'");
}
}

class Connections{
    public $players;
    public $website;

public function connect(){
     $players = new mysqli("*******", "*****", "*****", "*******");
     $website = new mysqli("*******", "*****", "******", "******");
}
}
?>
```

I hid the mysql login details, but I know that the ones I'm using are correct and working.

Comment: If there's a syntax error in your PHP code then activating error reporting in PHP will not work because the PHP will never be executed due to the syntax error.

Comment: In your `Connections` class - your variables in `connect()` should probably reference `$this->players` etc as they are currently only using function local variables.

Comment: @NigelRen That worked before though, so it can't be causing the error.

Comment: I'm not saying it's caused the error you have, but its still something that should be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> include("php.ini")

that has to hurt !!
I'm not certain that this is your only error but that line is definitely incorrect and will make your scrip crash

remove that no matter what

the path to the php.ini file is defined in your php/server setting, this will vary depending on your system but in no circumstance including that file within you php script can be valid, also the semi-coma after it is missing

Comment: Oh dear, that was it. I have no actual idea how I oversaw that. I'm sorry for wasting your time and thanks for helping.

Comment: also as mentionned  Nigel Ren your script has issues on how you are calling your attributes/methods like `$connections->$players`  or `$cons->$website`, these are incorrect and should look something like `$connections->players` and  `$this->cons->website`. This was not your question but you definitely want to fix those

Answer (score 0):

The main reason you're not getting any error, is because [`display_startup_errors`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-startup-errors) is off.

`include("php.ini")` wasn't your issue. (Although Nathanael brings up a valid point, that it's likely you're not including it correctly.) You can very well include a `php.ini` file if you so desire (Keep in mind it will process as a PHP file, and not an ini or configuration file). **The error lies with the lack of a semicolon (`;`) at the end of that line.** With `display_startup_errors` set on, it would have displayed any compiler time warnings and errors.